# How to play audio inline using IPython.display.audio

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

I want to play several audio files using IPython.display.Audio

I wrote the function:

```
import IPython.display

def display_midi(path, midi):
    print(path.name)
    IPython.display.Audio(midi.synthesize(), rate=16000)
```

The path printed to the screen, but the audio was not displayed. 
Any solutions?

**Edit**: I got few answers, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2):

```py
from music21 import midi

mf = midi.MidiFile()
mf.open(path) # path='abc.midi'
mf.read()
mf.close()
s = midi.translate.midiFileToStream(mf)
s.show('midi')
```

Comment: Yes. It does work. However, it keeps playing in the background if you don't stop. Even if the kernel is restarted